# OracleJet strange error : 'ojet add platform' is not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, oracle-jet

I tried to run a command : `ojet add platform=andorid` from command line but I got this strange error

```
ojet add platform is not supported
```

also when I run `ojet create JETmobileapp --hybrid --appid "com.oracle.JETmobileapp" --appname "JETmobileapp" --platform=android --template=navdrawer` I gives me an error:

```
 Error: (during validateFlags) Invalid flag: hybrid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS of JET v15.0.0 release, all support for Hybrid (Cordova) development was removed from the CLI.  The use of Hybrid with JET was deprecated with the JET v10 release about 3 years ago.